# VB.NET copy data from treevew to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, treeview

I want to copy some/all data from treeview to the datagridview
For example: if I select one node of a department or a company node, when I click a button I want all employees of that node to be copied to the datagridview with checking for repeatation.

Someone Please explain to me the mechanism of this.

This is the code I tried to write but I had difficulties to make it

```
For i = 0 To TreeView1.Nodes.Count - 1
        'MsgBox(i & " " & TreeView1.Nodes(i).Text)
        Dim node As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes(i)
        For j = 0 To node.Nodes.Count - 1
            'MsgBox(j & " " & node.Nodes(j).Text)
            Dim subnode As TreeNode = node.Nodes(j)
            For z = 0 To subnode.Nodes.Count - 1
                'MsgBox(z & " " & subnode.Nodes(z).Text)
                Dim Usubnode As TreeNode = subnode.Nodes(j)
                DGV.Rows(z).Cells(0).Value = subnode.Nodes(z).Name.ToString
                DGV.Rows(z).Cells(1).Value = subnode.Nodes(z).Text.ToString
            Next  '' z
        Next   ''j
    Next  '' i
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

[image]

the treeview was populated this way:

```
 For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim coName = dr("CompName").ToString()
        Dim coNodeId = "co" & dr("ID").ToString()

        ''''find or create the company node
        Dim nodes = TreeView2.Nodes.Find(coNodeId, True)
        Dim coNode As TreeNode

        If nodes.Length = False Then ''''didn't find: create and add
            coNode = New TreeNode()  {.Name = coNodeId, .Text = coName}
            TreeView2.Nodes.Add(coNode)

        Else ''''did find
            coNode = nodes(0)
        End If


        Dim depName = dr("depName").ToString()
        Dim depNodeId = "dep" & dr("depNum").ToString()

        ''''find or create the dep node under the co node
        nodes = coNode.Nodes.Find(depNodeId, True)
        Dim depNode As TreeNode

        If nodes.Length = 0 Then
            depNode = New TreeNode()  {.Name = depNodeId, .Text = depName}
            coNode.Nodes.Add(depNode)
        Else
            depNode = nodes(0)
        End If
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''create the emp node
        Dim EmpName = dr("EmpName").ToString()
        Dim empNodeId = "emp" & dr("EmpNum").ToString()

        ''''find or create the emp node under the dep node
        nodes = depNode.Nodes.Find(empNodeId, True)
        Dim empNode As TreeNode

        If nodes.Length = 0 Then
            empNode = New TreeNode()  {.Name = empNodeId, .Text = EmpName}
            depNode.Nodes.Add(empNode)
        Else
            empNode = nodes(0)
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: How did the treeview get populated?

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions in one thread. If you want to know which is the better method, why are you asking how to perform one of them? Ask one specific question and provide all information relevant to that question and only that question.

Comment: @Mary
I've editted the code to see how I populated the tree view.

Comment: @jmcilhinney 
I mentioned that to just know which method is better to use in this situation.
I guess this may lead someone to help me with the right way if I did that wronglly

Comment: It doesn't matter why you asked two questions.

Answer (score 0):

You populated the tree from a datatable. Bind the grid to the same table, through a BindingSource. While you are adding nodes, store a string in the Tag of the node to dictate a BindingSource filter:

```
depNode = New TreeNode()  {.Name = depNodeId, .Text = depName, .Tag = $"[depNum] = '{dr("depNum")}'"}
```

Put a different filter for each kind of node(co/dep/emp)

Add a handler to the treeview's AfterSelect event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-determine-which-treeview-node-was-clicked-windows-forms) and set the Filter property of the BindingSource to `e.Node.Tag.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks  @Caius Jard
I stored them each by its tag but I didn't understand how can I select a node to copy the employee nodes to the datagridvew!!

Comment: You don't select a node. The user of the app selects a node. You dont copy anything anywhere; the datagridview already knows about ALL employees. When the user selects a node you set the filter of the bindingsource and the list of all employees is filtered to only some employees

Comment: Ok bro I got it. 
but what if I want to choose employees from different departments to be added to the grid so that I can perform tasks on them, how can I do that?

Comment: You can get all the selected nodes and string.Join their Tags with " OR " as a separator so that the filter string becomes eg "[empid] = 1 OR [depNum] = 2" - basically the filter string each one has can be built into being a bigger string of A or B or C etc... and you can use the same code for one row or 100 rows, because the string.Join of just one item is the same thing as the item. It might be something like `bindingsource.Filter = string.Join(" OR ", treeview.SelectedNodes.Select(n=>n.Tag))`